# API Filtering in Rest

Tags: java, sql, api, rest

I have a requirement where the user wants to filter the table through REST API(GET call) (The API filtering should allow using parenthesis for defining operations precedence and use any combination of the available fields. The supported operations should include or, and, eq (equals), ne (not equals), gt (greater than), lt (lower than), in, like)

Use case example:

Consider the table having a column user_id,first_name,last_name,food_intake_calories,created_at

Query should support (created_at eq '2016-05-01') AND ((food_intake_calories gt 20) OR (food_intake_calories lt 10)).

I first thought of taking input replacing eq with "=" and ne with "!=" and then directly append this to where clause of sql and run the query but this will again invite SQL injection. I am clueless about how to take care of this. I am using java with dropwizard as a backend server.

Comment: You might still get downvotes for the "does any framework exist" bit if it's construed as you asking for a software recommendation (off topic)

Comment: @CaiusJard will remove thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be using [Jexl](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/index.html) expression parser to formalize this parsing.

It is possible to replace some braces and use custom code to paese the request, but slowly the requirements change and you get a convoluted code that parses the REST request.

Answer (score 0):

OData would be right way to go. It has specifications designed for user use-case. Advantage of using such a standard way of representing data is that everyone can consumer your API as long as they follow the standard OData querying.

Checkout: https://www.odata.org/

Hope this helps !!

Comment: On a quick google search I couldnt find any good articles. Usually OData is the standard for REST in terms of querying database. I was part of team in my previous company where we developed the same. But we mostly did it ourselves following the protocol. I will checkout if there are any orm which support this and will comment it here if I find one. By the there are lots of paid tools with can help u achieve this

Comment: While I am a strong believer in standardization of stuff, this is one of the worst standards I have seen. I'd rather migrate to graphql than write parsers for odata. No wonder this is the first time I'm hearing about it. I wonder if some of these queries would even get through OWASP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's necessarily a problem passing responsibility for parsing the full expression on to sql so long as you check it first. You could devise a set of rules:

- replace brackets with nothing
- split on AND and OR
- the set of statements that remain must be of the form `column operator 'value'`
- column must be in the set of known columns
- operator must be in the set of known operators
- value must start and end with a ' and everything between will be taken as a value
- substitute the actual `value` for a db parameter placeholder and put the given data value into that parameter's value - put the values into a hash map key set to dedupe them, then replace them in the original api query string  one by one, adding them as parameters to your db command as you go
- you now end up with a state where the query is suitable for running against a db without injection risk- the columns and operators are in a known set and the values are parameterized
- you might want to consider limiting the number of results or executions/amount of db time that may be devoted to these queries if the predicates are so free form